# nmap & ssl-enum-ciphers

Tags: ssl, nmap

I am trying to check for the offered ciphers with `nmap`:

```
$ nmap -Pn --script ssl-enum-ciphers host1.example.org -p 443
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-13 14:52 CET
Nmap scan report for host1.example.org (129.132.65.51)
Host is up (0.0070s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.39 seconds
```

It's working fine but for a single case:

- Fedora 35 (host1.example.org) from macOS

```
$ nmap -Pn --script ssl-enum-ciphers host1.example.org -p 443
Starting Nmap 7.92 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-13 14:52 CET
Nmap scan report for host1.example.org (129.132.65.51)
Host is up (0.0070s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_CCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.39 seconds
```

- Fedora 35 (host1.example.org) from Fedora 35 (host2.example.org)

```
$ nmap -Pn --script ssl-enum-ciphers host1.example.org -p 443
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-13 14:55 CET
Nmap scan report for host1.example.org (129.132.65.51)
Host is up (0.013s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.35 seconds
```

- Same machines other direction. Fedora 35 (host2.example.org) from Fedora 35 (host1.example.org)

```
$ nmap -Pn --script ssl-enum-ciphers host2.example.org -p 443
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-12-13 14:56 CET
Nmap scan report for host2.example.org (138.201.94.172)
Host is up (0.013s latency).
Other addresses for host2.example.org (not scanned): 2a01:4f8:c17:cbd8::2

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.65 seconds
```

I don't really get why both Fedora machines give a result from macOS but not when scanning from `host1.example.org` to `host2.example.org` when both should be configured in the same way.

How can I debug the proble

Answer (score 0):

`host1` is only offering TLS 1.3. I was using two different versions of `nmap`: 7.91 (without TLS 1.3 support) and 7.92 (with TLS 1.3 support).